# A box with 3 red balls and 2 white balls. 3 balls taken randomly with replacement,

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A box containing 3 red balls and 2 white balls. A ball is taken randomly and with replacement. This is done 3 times.

- What is the probability that exactly one red ball is obtained?
- Probability at least 1 red ball is obtained?

---

---

**Attempt**

For the first part, the possibilities are: red ball at 1st draw, red ball at 2nd draw, or red ball at 3rd draw. The probabiity for each is $p = \frac{3}{5} \frac{2}{5} \frac{2}{5}$, so the answer is $3 \times p$.

For the second part, possibilities are: 1 red ball taken, 2 red balls taken, or 3 red balls taken. probability of 2 red balls taken is: $3 \times \frac{3}{5} \frac{3}{5} \frac{2}{5}$. So answer is: 
$$ \left( 3 \times \frac{3}{5} \frac{2}{5} \frac{2}{5} \right) + \left( 3 \times \frac{3}{5} \frac{3}{5} \frac{2}{5} \right) + \frac{3}{5}\frac{3}{5}\frac{3}{5} $$

Comment: Yes.  The second can also be calculated as the probability not all samples are white, i.e. $1- \frac{2}{5} \frac{2}{5} \frac{2}{5}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both parts are correct. As regards the second one, it is  easier to evaluate the complement:  the probability that at least one red ball is obtained is $1$ minus the probability that all the three balls are white, namely
$$1-\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^3.$$